# maven scm:checkin error

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-scm

My maven script generates a laconic "`error 1`", and I am a bit at a loss as to how to extract the root cause from the huge output.
Could you help me in isolating said root cause for this error?

Here is the command I used:

```
mvn scm:checkin -Dmessage="check in" 
error 1. 
List item [DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-scm-plugin:1.5:checkin' with basic configurator --> [DEBUG] (f)

basedir = E:\workspace\mtest [DEBUG] (f) 
connectionType = developerConnection [DEBUG] (s) 
connectionUrl = scm:svn:https://192.168.10.44/svn/FTMobileAdNetwork/trunk/personal/xuhuiw/mvntest/mtest/ 
[DEBUG] (f) developerConnectionUrl = scm:svn:https://192.168.10.44/svn/FTMobileAdNetwork/trunk/personal/xuhuiw/mvntest/mtest/ 
[DEBUG] (s) includes = src/*,pom.xml 
[DEBUG] (f) message = check in my mtest [DEBUG] (f) password = wangxuhui [DEBUG] (f) pushChanges = true 
[DEBUG] (f) settings = org.apache.maven.execution.SettingsAdapter@2d0479 
[DEBUG] (f) username = xuhuiw 
[DEBUG] (s) workingDirectory = E:\workspace\mtest [DEBUG] -- end configuration -- 
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "svn --username xuhuiw --password ***** --no-auth-cache --non-interactive commit --file C:\Users\xuhuiw\AppData\Local\Temp\maven-scm-2074558159.commit --targets C:\Users\xuhuiw\AppData\Local\Temp\maven-scm-5719724778329125171-targets" 
[INFO] Working directory: E:\workspace\mtest 
[ERROR] Provider message: 
[ERROR] The svn command failed. 
[ERROR] Command output: 
[ERROR] svn: 'E:\workspace\mtest' is not a working copy 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-scm-plugin:1.5:checkin (default-cli) on project mtest: Command failed.The svn command failed. -> 
[Help 1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-scm-plugin:1.5:checkin (default-cli) on project mtest: Command failed.
The svn command failed. at 
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217) at 
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153) at 
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145) at 
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84) at 
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59) at 
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183) at 
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161) at 
org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319) at 
org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156) at 
org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537) at 
org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196) at 
org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at 
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290) at 
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230) at 
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352) Caused by: 
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command failed.The svn command failed. at 
org.apache.maven.scm.plugin.AbstractScmMojo.checkResult(AbstractScmMojo.java:439) at 
org.apache.maven.scm.plugin.CheckinMojo.execute(CheckinMojo.java:83) at 
org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101) at 
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209) 
... 19 more 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR]
```

And here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"> 
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> 
  <groupId>com.ftad.common.mtest</groupId> 
  <artifactId>mtest</artifactId> 
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version> 
  <packaging>jar</packaging> 
  <name>mtest</name> <url>http://maven.apache.org</url> 
  <organization> 
    <name>众合广告</name> 
  </organization> 
  <properties> 
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-</project.build.sourceEncoding> </properties> 
    <scm> 
      <connection>scm:svn:https://192.168.10.44/svn/FTMobileAdNetwork/trunk/personal/xuhuiw/mvntest/mtest/</connection>
      <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://192.168.10.44/svn/FTMobileAdNetwork/trunk/personal/xuhuiw/mvntest/mtest/</developerConnection> 
    </scm> 
    <dependencies> 
      <dependency> 
        <groupId>junit</groupId> 
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId> 
        <version>4.7</version> 
      </dependency> 
    </dependencies> 
    <build> 
      <pluginManagement> 
         <plugins> 
           <plugin> 
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
             <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId> 
             <version>1.5</version> 
             <configuration> 
               <password>wangxuhui</password> 
               <username>xuhuiw</username> 
               <basedir>./</basedir> 
               <exportDirectory>target</exportDirectory> 
               <includes>src/*,pom.xml</includes> 
               <workingDirectory>./</workingDirectory> 
             </configuration> 
             <executions> 
               <execution> 
                 <id>pref-scm</id> 
                 <configuration> 
                    <includes>src/*,pom.xml</includes>
                    <checkoutDirectory>./</checkoutDirectory> 
                 </configuration> 
                 <goals> 
                   <goal>checkin</goal> 
                   <goal>checkout</goal> 
                   <goal>update</goal> 
                   <goal>add</goal> 
                   <goal>validate</goal> 
                 </goals> 
               </execution>
             </executions> 
           </plugin> 
         </plugins> 
       </pluginManagement> 
     </build> 
   <distributionManagement> 
     <site> 
       <id>apache.website</id> 
         <url>scp://people.apache.org/www/maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin</url> 
     </site> 
     <repository> 
       <id>releases</id>
       <url>http://192.168.10.6:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url> 
     </repository>
     <snapshotRepository> 
       <id>snapshots</id> 
       <url>http://192.168.10.6:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url> 
     </snapshotRepository> 
  </distributionManagement> 
</project>
```

Comment: Try to add your post according to the edit help. Keep separate: what is my question (plain text), what is the stack trace (indented by 4 spaces), what is the POM (indented by 4 spaces).

Comment: @mliebelt: agreed. I tried to add some semblance of a question in there ;) Note: the latest blog (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/se-podcast-19/) mentions: "New changes to the site are in the works. For example, no more duplicate title, and no more “Here code. You fix.” questions will be allowed." This was a close one.

Answer (score 1):

The important part is:

```
svn: 'E:\workspace\mtest' is not a working copy
```

So make sure your Maven task execute itself in an SVN working copy.

Comment: How to make sure that my working directory to the copy directory svn， I use maven to create the project, what you need to do

Comment: @user958420 I don't know the Maven scm task enough, but since the basedir is based on the current directory '.', try executing your maven repo from an SVN working tree.

Comment: my svn tree    ---trunk
    ----personal
          ------xuhuiw
            ----mvntest
            ---mtest

Answer (score 1):

The directory you execute the scm:checkin from needs to be a svn working directory, which means you should have a ".svn" in that directory with the correct contents inside(the .svn is the svn admin directory which contains the pristine files downloaded).

Check if your .svn directory exists or if it's empty ( i found out that when I used "includes=*" in the checkout execution configuration, maven wipes out the .svn directory), which caused the subsequent scm:checkin to fail. And in your case, since you are using "includes=src/*,pom.xml", your .svn directory might not even exist.

To fix this, you can define execution for checkout in the maven-scm-plugin first (without using includes), then define a separate execution for add/check. And here's a pom.xml to do scm:checkout, curl download, then scm:checkin
http://mywallstreettechjob.blogspot.com/2015/06/maven-scm-plugin-pomxml-sample-for-svn.html